# Need help installing pear, pecl and pecl->ps

Tags: installation, pear, pecl, yum, ps

The end goal is to be able to read/write/exec postscript files using PECL -> PS which I believe to be included within PEAR.

I have done all the basics `# yum update`, `# yum install php-pear`. However, I can't use PEAR with php scripts, but can via ssh. I think I need to update some .ini files but which ones??

System: Linux virtual server, CentosOS 5.

Update:
I did as follows

```
# cd /usr/share/
# wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
# php go-pear.phar
```

which unpacked everything at /usr/share/pear and updated the /etc/php.ini with `include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear:"`.  Now when I use `echo get_include_path();` it displays as expected but still cant include or require 'pear.php'. `# pear version` returns PEAR Version: 1.9.4 - so it works...

Answer (score 1):

you need to change to change the php.ini settings file in the php folder.basically you have to  un comment a line regarding the extension,to activate it! here is a link for refernce:
http://phphints.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/installing-pear-package-manager-on-wamp/